# php replace all strings in array, and output comma seperated string

Tags: php

Wrote a little snippet that replaces all strings in an array, and finally outputs them as a comma separated string (shown below).

It seems a bit much though for such simple functionality. So my question is can anyone come up with a more elegant way of writing this?

```
$arr = array('first', 'second', 'third');
$size = count($arr);
$newArr = array();

for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {

    $newArr[$i] = str_replace($arr[$i], '?', $arr[$i]);

}

$final = implode(', ', $newArr);

echo $final;
```

Comment: This question is more suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Isn't the code a bit pointless? I mean it always replaces all of the array elements with "?", because you are passing `$arr[$i]` as both the needle and input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace()` accepts arrays:

```
$newArr = str_replace($arr, '?', $arr);
$final = implode(', ', $newArr);
```

But I hope this was just an example as you are just replacing anything in the array with ? which is easier done.

Answer (score 1):

An other form to your snippet...

```
    <?php
       $arr = array('first', 'second', 'third');
       foreach ($arr as $item) {
           $na[] = str_replace($item, '?', $item);
       }
       echo implode(', ', $na);
```

Hope help you!